# find intersections between range tuples with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of ranges like this:

```
[
(1,3),
(13,13),
(14,16),
(15,19),
]
```

In which I need to find intersecting ranges.
In this case it would be the third and fourth line. What is an efficient way to do this in numpy?

Comment: does it have to be with numpy? or pandas is fine too?

Comment: pandas is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a column that tells you if a row is overlapping with its *next* interval:

```
a = np.array([(1,3),(13,13),(14,16),(15,19)])
a.sort()
intervals = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['start','end'])
print((intervals.end-intervals.start.shift(-1))>0)
```

output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
```

Find the index of overlapping intervals:

```
idx = np.array(np.where((intervals.end-intervals.start.shift(-1))>0))
print(np.hstack((idx,idx+1)))
#[[2 3]]
```

You can do similar with numpy. You have to either write the shift function or use scipy to shift or use numpy.roll.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done without a module, you can use the `set.intersection()` method:

```
l = [(1,3),
     (13,13),
     (14,16),
     (15,19)]

print([(l[i-1],t) for i,t in enumerate(l) if set(range(t[0],t[1])).intersection(range(l[i-1][0],l[i-1][1]))])
```

Output:

```
[((14, 16), (15, 19))]
```